# C# NAudio read CC-parameter thru midi from hardware synth. Is it possible?

Tags: c#, midi, naudio

I wanna get value of certain CC-midi parameter of hardware synth (cutoff or resonance value, e.g.). I can set this parameter, but can't read. Is it possible?

Comment: It's probably possible. Try showing us what you have tried so far and we can help you from there.

Answer (score 0):

Most synthesizers can read single parameters with SysEx commands (or all parameters at all with a bulk dump).
All these commands are vendor specific; to find out what specific command you have to send, look into your synth's manual.